# Quite frequent SSLPeerUnverifedException with PoolingClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

On a system we are using PoolingClientConnectionManager 4.2.1 (we currently cannot update it because of other dependencies).

When there is more than a certain amount of requests, we start getting SSLPeerUnverifiedExceptions for single requests and I currently cannot figure out why, also because some of the Javadoc only shows "deprecated".

Here's the setup for the pooling:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault();
Scheme https = getHttpsScheme(sslContext, port);
schemeRegistry.register(https);

PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
            new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(20);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

return new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager);
```

Here are the logs:

Attempt working:

`PoolingClientConnectionManager "Connection request: [route: {s}->https://myserver][total kept alive: 20; route allocated: 20 of 20; total allocated: 20 of 20]" 
DefaultClientConnection  "Connection 0.0.0.0:49954<->[server_ip]:443 closed" 
PoolingClientConnectionManager   "Connection leased: [id: 94198][route: {s}->https://myserver][total kept alive: 19; route allocated: 20 of 20; total allocated: 20 of 20]" 
DefaultClientConnectionOperator  "Connecting to myserver:443"`

Failed attempt:

`PoolingClientConnectionManager "Connection request: [route: {s}->https://myserver ][total kept alive: 19; route allocated: 20 of 20; total allocated: 20 of 20]" 
DefaultClientConnection  "Connection 0.0.0.0:49953<->[server_ip]:443 closed" 
PoolingClientConnectionManager  "Connection leased: [id: 94196][route: {s}->https://myserver ][total kept alive: 18; route allocated: 20 of 20; total allocated: 20 of 20]" 
DefaultClientConnectionOperator "Connecting to myserver:443" 
DefaultClientConnection "Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@4821fdeb closed" 
DefaultClientConnection "Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@4821fdeb shut down" 
PoolingClientConnectionManager "Connection [id: 94196][route: {s}->https://myserver ] can be kept alive for 9223372036854775807 MILLISECONDS" 
DefaultClientConnection  "Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@4821fdeb closed" 
PoolingClientConnectionManager "Connection released: [id: 94196][route: {s}->https://myserver ][total kept alive: 18; route allocated: 19 of 20; total allocated: 19 of 20]"`

Besides on how to get rid of the exception, I wonder

- if the pool is to small because all routes are permanently allocated
- if the time-to-live I passed as a constructor arg (5000 ms) is respected, when it says "can be kept alive for 9223372036854775807 MILLISECONDS"
- why the connection was shut down in the failed attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of the problem by adding a re-try in case of the exception with closing expired and idle connections beforehand.

```
...
    try {
        result = performWsRequest(request, soapAction);
    } catch (WebServiceIOException | SSLPeerUnverifiedException ex) {
        if (retryAttempt) {
            logAndThrowExceptionUponWsRequest(ex);
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Re-trying webservice-request");
            cleanConnections();
            result = performWsRequestWithRetry(request, soapAction, true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logAndThrowExceptionUponWsRequest(e);
    }
...

private synchronized void cleanConnections() {

    LOGGER.info(
            "Cleaning connections. Total message-senders: {}",
            this.webServiceTemplate.getMessageSenders().length);

    for (WebServiceMessageSender messageSender : this.webServiceTemplate.getMessageSenders()) {

        if (messageSender instanceof HttpComponentsMessageSender) {

            LOGGER.info("Checking connections of message-sender {}", messageSender);
            HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = (HttpComponentsMessageSender)messageSender;

            if (httpComponentsMessageSender.getHttpClient() != null
                && httpComponentsMessageSender.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager() != null) {
                LOGGER.info("Closing connections");
                httpComponentsMessageSender.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
                httpComponentsMessageSender.getHttpClient()
                        .getConnectionManager()
                        .closeIdleConnections(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out the problem are the certificates of the backend-nodes causing renegotiation to fail. As a workaround jvm arguments have been enriched with  -Djdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange=true and -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true